# How to solve $e^{2x - 1} = -x^2 + 3x - 0.25$

Tags: special-functions, lambert-w, newton-raphson, transcendental-equations

I know the answer is $x=0.5$, but I only know it because my calculator showed me the intersection point of the two graphs. What I want to know is how to get to this result algebraically. I've tried to use the Lambert-W function, but I ended up with $$W((1-2x)/(-x^2+3x-0.25))=1-2x$$ and this didn't help me either. If smn has an idea on how to solve this, pls let me know.
Obs: I don't know how to use the Newton-raphson's method, so that's why I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the two curves $y=e^{2x-1}$ and the parabola $y=-x^2+3x-0.25$

They have the same value $y=1$ at $x=0.5$

Furthermore $y'=2e^{2x-1}$ and $y'(0.5)=2$ so the tangent line at $(0.5,1)$ has equation $y-1=2(x-0.5)\to y=2x$

For the parabola $y'=-2x+3$ and $y'(0.5)=2$

the tangent at $(0.5,1)$ is the same than the exponential curve.

The curves are tangent at $(0.5,1)$

$y''=4e^{2x-1}$ is positive at $x=0.5$ while for the parabola $y''=-2$ is negative for any $x$ so the parabola has convexity down (is less than the tangent in any $x$), while the exponential has convexity up (is more than the tangent at any $x$)

So $x=0.5$ is the one and only solution of the equation

Hope it helps

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get everything that you wrote, and why is $x=0.5$ the only solution to this problem. Though, my question was on how to get to $x=0.5$. It'd be nice if you could help me on understanding this. Sorry if I haven't made myself clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For
$$e^{2x-1} + x^2 = 3 x - \frac{1}{4}$$
it can be seen that
\begin{align}
e^{2x-1} + x^2 &= 3 x - \frac{1}{4} \\
e^{2x -1} + x^{2} - x + \frac{1}{4} &= 2 x = 2 \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right) + 1 \\
e^{2 x -1} + \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} - 2 \left( x - \frac{1}{2} \right) + 1 &= 2 \\
e^{2 x - 1} + \left( \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right) - 1 \right)^{2} &= 2 \\
e^{2 \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)} + \left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)^{2} &= 2.
\end{align}
The only solution to this equation is 
$$x = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Tks for your answer. Just one thing that I didn't get about your solution: in the very last part, in which you wrote that \begin{align} e^{2 \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)} + \left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)^{2} &= 2. \end{align} in order to find out that the result is $x = \frac{1}{2}$ did you simply deduced it by observing the equation, or is there some other step that you haven't written?

Comment: @LucasCampos For the last equation the only value of $x$ that eliminates the exponential term is $x = 1/2$. Alternatively, graphing the function of $x$ on the left and the constant line on the right show that they intersect only once at $x=1/2$.